# Is there some error on this BubbleSort pseudocode? (or I'm taking it wrong)?

Tags: pseudocode, bubble-sort

I saw this on a book:

```
BubbleSort( list )
    length  <-- lenght of list
    do  {
        swapped_pair    <-- false
        index       <-- 1
        while index <= length - 1 {
            if list[index] > list[index + 1] {
                swap( list[index], list[index + 1] )
                swapped_pair = true
                index <-- index + 1
            }
        }
    } while( swapped = true )
end
```

In the pseudocode above the index is increased only `if list[index] > list[index + 1]` because the `index <-- index + 1` is inside the IF-loop.

So `if list[index] > list[index + 1]` is not true, then the next lines which are:

```
            swap( list[index], list[index + 1] )
            swapped_pair = true
            index <-- index + 1
```

won't be executed. That includes `index <-- index + 1`

This will cause that if the first two variables are sorted correctly, then the code won't check the next two variables because index won't increase in that case.

And then `while index <= length - 1` will always be true because the index is never increased, and maybe the code will be stuck at `while index <= length - 1` loop.

Shouldn't the index be placed outside of the IF-loop?

Like this:

```
BubbleSort( list )
    length  <-- lenght of list
    do  {
        swapped_pair    <-- false
        index       <-- 1
        while index <= length - 1 {
            if list[index] > list[index + 1] {
                swap( list[index], list[index + 1] )
                swapped_pair = true
            }
            index <-- index + 1
        }
    } while( swapped = true )
end
```

So that `if list[index] > list[index + 1]` then they are swaped and swapped pair set to true. If `if list[index] > list[index + 1]` is not true, the index is increased by 1 by using `index <-- index + 1`.

And since while-loop continues because still `index <= length - 1`, the process from `IF` will repeat again and again until index 0 and 1 to index n-1 and 1.

**Is my version of the pseudocode right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The condition in the inner while loop needs to have a way of changing after each iteration.